# Server that transfers FTP to FTPS without downloading on my PC

Tags: unix, ftp, shared-hosting, ftps

I need to do a server to server transfer, and the data is about 1 TB in size. One server supports plain FTP, but the other mandates FTPS. Both servers are located in the US. If the data was within a GB I could download it onto my PC via FTP and upload via FTPS. I'm located in India where speeds are about 1 Mbit/sec (100 KB per sec). Downloading 1 TB onto my PC would take days and re-uploading it would take days. No chance of using wget because I have SSH/root access to neither. All I got is FTP(S).

What if there was a US server that could open 2 FTP(S) connections, and transfer data directly between 2 servers?  That way it would be very fast (at least 10-50 MB/sec?) and I could complete the transfer within a day. Is there such a service, or can it be built with a script running on a US VPS server?

Comment: Can't practically any ftp server do this?  At least, any good one can.

Comment: Remember I have SSH/root access to NEITHER. If I can do this via an FTP client, well and good. I've tried many clients but I've always been unable to set this up. Pingback if you know of any FTP Client that can initiate a direct server-to-server transfer, without using your PC as a middleman.

Comment: Why don't you just set up an Amazon EC2 instance in between? Pull from one FTP to the EC2 instance, then upload from it to the second FTP. You'll be on Amazon's network with all the bandwidth that entails.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you think this is a noob question then you obviously don't understand it. Please take the time to read it first, before downvoting just because the explanation's too long!

Comment: @ceejayoz - And how do I "pull form one FTP" to EC2? I've never used EC2.

Comment: This really doesn't seem to be a system administration issue.

Comment: @Geotarget You'd fire up an EC2 instance - Linux or Windows, whichever you're more comfortable with - install your FTP client of choice, and do it there. If it's a Linux instance you've got full shell, if it's Windows you've got RDP for the GUI.

Comment: @lain - Why not? Just because I'm not a sysadmin at a datacenter, this is NOT a sysadmin issue?

Comment: We generally expect people solving sysamin issues to have suitable levels of access to the system. Without suitable access you're just a user of someone else's system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a client that supports FXP (see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) and make server to server transfer.